# Intermediate results as variables or only base values?

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I have a object which has a few base variables (integers as example) and one intermediate variable for further processing. The intermediate variable can be calculated from the base vars. Now the question: Should I always repeat the calculation of the intermediate var from the base vars or should I save the value and only change it if the base vars change? (I need access to every var in pseudo random order.)

Two examples in C++-Code.

Caching the result:

```
class Test
{
  private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    int x;

    void calcX ()
    {
        // Just an example for a calculation for x.
        x = ((a + 10) * (b / (c*c + 1)));
    }

  public:
    void setA (int var)
    {
        a = var;
        calcX();
    }
    void setB (int var)
    {
        b = var;
        calcX();
    }
    void setC (int var)
    {
        c = var;
        calcX();
    }

    // Every var has a get methode.
}
```

Always recalculating the result:

```
class Test
{
  private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    int x;

  public:
    // Var a, b and c have get and set methodes.

    int getX ()
    {
        return ((a + 10) * (b / (c*c + 1)));
    }
}
```

So, which way is considered better? I really don't know. We should not save the intermediate value because it would be redundant, but then again we should not recalculate the value again and again.

Comment: Some unrelated observations - it is good practice to avoid non-const getter members such as your implementation of getX() in the second example. Similarly, your setter members should have a single responsibility, namely setting a private member and not calling calcX(). There are good reasons for this including making your life easier when testing and debugging.

Comment: @JamesR: Yeah, in real code I would make the get methodes constant. In my opinion the job of set methodes is to ensure the consistence of the value(s). Why should I use set methodes if they can't do anything to ensure the correctness of all variables? Could you make an example how I should ensure that x has the correct value for the momentary a, b and c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

If you need to calculate once, and use million times, then the answer is obvious: the first case wins.

If you need to calculate every time, or quite often, then pick what you prefer. Your function doesn't read from a file, and has no slow operations, so it will not make a huge difference.

Avoid premature optimization.

When optimizing, it is best to measure. Profile the code and optimize only the bottlenecks. Everything else is a microoptimization, and should be avoided.

Comment: I was more thinking about a general aspect, like "Try to avoid problems with inconsistent redundant code", but thanks. :)

Comment: As has already mentioned avoid premature optimization tendencies. If you are genuinely concerned about performance then run a profiler over your code and see where the actual bottlenecks are located.